# how to do API testing automation with soapui

Tags: automation, soapui

Is it possible to do API automation testing using soapui? I am new to this and my company expects everything to be automated. They wanted me to write test cases in eclipse . How to write soapui testcases in eclipse? can anyone refer any good sites for learning soapui automation in eclipse? Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible: it's what soapUI does.

Since you're just starting out with soapUI, good places to discover the product's capabilities are the [Info page here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/soapui/info) and the soapUI web site itself.

Then, the best advice is to download the open source version of soapUI and begin exploring. It comes with some sample projects to get you started. Search for soapUI on Amazon and you'll find a handful of books to give you a deeper dive.

Plus, learn Groovy: it'll help you become an automation guru.

And, when you hit specific problems or issues, [ask a question here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and someone will likely be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you to go and familiarize yourself with the actual [SoapUI tool](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html) and not with the [Eclipse plugin](https://www.soapui.org/soapui-for-ide/eclipse/eclipse-plugin.html) which is awfully outdated.

The documentation on [soapui.org](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started.html) it is written as a handbook in both API Testing and the world of SoapUI so that is a great starting point.

In essence, you create your testsuites and testcases in the tool and then save the project. The XML-file that is the project can then be executed upon by using either the [maven-plugins](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html) or [the testrunner](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html) as part of an automation suite in whatever way you may wish. The test-results can even be exported as JUnit reports and be slurped by CI servers like Jenkins and TeamCity.

Also, as mentioned by @craigcaulfield, knowing [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) and the [SoapUI object model](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/the-soapui-object-model.html) is a really powerful tool within SoapUI to test the corner-cases.

Good luck and Happy testing!